# Calculate the sum with minimum usage of numbers

Tags: algorithm

How can I achieve a sum from using minimum set of magic numbers?
Magic numbers are integers having a combination of only 0's and 1's, such as `0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111`..... and so on.

Examples:

```
23 requires 3 magic numbers - 11 + 11 + 1
120 requires 2 magic numbers -  110 + 10
```

**What I tried:**

My idea was to start with the magic number closest to the sum, but that would not result with minimum number of magic numbers.

For example, in case of the sum 120, the magic number closest to 120 is 111, which leaves me with 9. However, to add the missing 9 the total number of magic numbers required is 10 `[111 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1]`

However, 120 can be reached with just 2 magic numbers - [`110 + 10`]- which means my logic doesn't yield the correct result.

---

The question has already been answered , I am just trying to improve the question.

Comment: Do you have any idea on your own?

Comment: @Flown , Not really, I am thinking a lot, but its all non sense ideas. that's why i have approached the community

Comment: we might help you if you have an issue with you implementation

Comment: My idea was to get the max magic number that is closer  to the sum, but that would not result with minimum magic numbers

Comment: The idea is good. Give an example where this idea is not working...

Comment: @Flown, in case of 120, the max magic number close to 120 is 111, now that leaves me with 9. If i approach with this solution it takes me 10(111 + 9*1) magic numbers.  but i can reach 120 with 2 magic numbers(110+10)

Comment: What I would suggest is to brute force the search of the solution (i.e. try every possible permutation until it gives the result, starting from the lowest). Then once you solved it with this "brutal" way, try finding a more elegant solution. Hint: Eran's answer might help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a hint:

> 2**3** : 1**1** + 1**1**+ **1** ( **3**  magic numbers)
>
> 1**2**0: 1**1**0+ **1**0 (**2** magic numbers)

The highest digit in the target number is the answer, since you need exactly `k` magic numbers (all having 1 in the relevant position) in order for the sum to contain the digit `k`.

So the algorithm would start by splitting the target sum into digits. For example, if the input is 3052, you should create the following array:

```
int[] digits = {3,0,5,2};
```

While you split the target sum into digits, you can also find the largest digit.

```
int max = 5;
```

Now we know we need 5 magic numbers, and all that remains is actually finding them. You can do so by iterating over the array of the digits `max` times.

In each iteration you create a single magic number whose `1` digits correspond with positive values of the array. You also decrement those values.

1st iteration:

```
3,0,5,2 ->  create magic number 1011 & decrement the array values to 2,0,4,1
```

2nd iteration:

```
2,0,4,1 ->  create magic number 1011 & decrement the array values to 1,0,3,0
```

3rd iteration:

```
1,0,3,0 ->  create magic number 1010 & decrement the array values to 0,0,2,0
```

4th iteration:

```
0,0,2,0 ->  create magic number   10 & decrement the array values to 0,0,1,0
```

5th iteration:

```
0,0,1,0 ->  create magic number   10 & decrement the array values to 0,0,0,0
```

We are done, the magic numbers are 1011 + 1011 + 1010 + 10 + 10 = 3052.

Comment: That what would be your solution in case of 971? Can you reach the sum with 9 magic numbers?

Comment: @occasionalvisitor 111 + 110 + 110 + 110 + 110 + 110 + 110 + 100 + 100

Comment: do you have any implementation algorithm for the same or any material that i can go through for the implementation

Comment: @occasionalvisitor No, but it should be pretty straight forward.